# About DigiSpark (arduino) keyboard library

Tags: c++, arduino

I need to rewrite the DigiKeyboard ([reference)](https://github.com/digistump/DigisparkArduinoIntegration/blob/master/libraries/DigisparkKeyboard/DigiKeyboard.h) `sendKeyStroke(byte keyStroke)` according to the behavior explained below:

1. The original behavior is to poll the USB and check for a KeyStroke, if it detects any data, it sends the stroke via USB and the computer registers it as a single click. The problem with this implementation is that I **cannot** hold the input (that generates the KeyStroke) and have constant/persistent signal to be read by the PC. The way it works is that it polls within every loop and sends **one** stroke every iteration
2. What I need to have is a single and persistent signal instead of multiple signals every second whenever the input is being held down.

What I know is that the Arduino Leonardo implements this with the `Keyboard.press(byte)` method. I can't find the implementation to rewrite it using DigiSpark's library, but I do believe it should be possible since it has a native API for keyboard.

Essentially, I think the optimal scenario would have a blocking function that sends a persistent signal over USB which could be used in an pin interruption (is this possible or would the blocking behavior bug the interrupt?) while I do other things in the main loop and other interruptions.

Is there anyway I could rewrite the DigiSpark's `sendKeyStroke(byte)` or even use Leonardo's library to create the behavior I need?

Comment: Instead of using blocking calls, you could turn your main loop into a state machine, where the sending of keystrokes becomes a series of states (wait for interrupt ready, set interrupt, wait for interrupt ready).  That way you are free to do other stuff at your discretion without performing sleeps.

Comment: Well that's a way of implementing the data transfer while doing other things, but I can't see how that would contribute to the main problem (the persistent signal). Thanks for the feedback anyways